# Upload файла по ws-протоколу

Tags: node.js, websocket

Пытаюсь отправить файл на сервер по `ws://` параллельно отправляемой форме, сервер получает его вот так:

```
module.exports = function(server) {

var clients = {};

var webSocketServer = new WebSocketServer.Server({ server });

  webSocketServer.on('connection', function(ws) {

    var id = Math.random();
    clients[id] = ws;
    console.log("новое соединение " + id);

    ws.on('message', function(data) {

        console.log(data);

        var writeStream = fs.createWriteStream('d:/.../file_ws.jpg');
        writeStream.write(data);

        ws.on('end', function () {
            writeStream.end();
        });

        ws.on('error', function (err) {
            console.error(err);
        });

    });

    ws.on('close', function() {
        console.log('соединение закрыто ' + id);
        delete clients[id];
    });
  });

};
```

Всё благополучно достигает цели - поля формы на месте, файл лежит там, где ему и указано, он совершенно нормальный и даже иконка показана, страница перезагружается, соединение ws разрывается и создаётся новое соединение, но ... файл остаётся недоступным - "файл обрабатывается другой программой", - файл остаётся каким-то образом под контролем сервера. То есть до тех пор, пока я не отключу сервер вообще. И как его отцепить?

Comment: вы проверяли, случается ли у вас `ws.on('end'` или нет?

Comment: @Darth вообще-то нет, но щас посмотрю.

Comment: @Darth Действительно, не случается. А что ему надо?

Comment: а ничего. message сокета это вроде как не поток, а пакет.. у него end и не должно быть.

Comment: @Darth Всё, я понЯл уже. Просто заменил поток на fs.writeFile Спасибо. Если нужны "баллы" - напишите одно слово в ответ.

Comment: @Darth Баллы не нужны. Лучше задавайте побольше качественных вопросов)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так

```
module.exports = function(server) {
    const clients = {};
    const webSocketServer = new WebSocketServer.Server({server});
    webSocketServer.on('connection', ws => {
        const id = Math.random();
        clients[id] = ws;
        console.log('новое соединение', id);
        // Получение файла
        ws.on('message', data => {
            console.log('получен файл', data);
            const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream('d:/.../file_ws.jpg');
            writeStream.write(data);
            writeStream.end();
        });
        ws.on('close', reason => {
            console.log('соединение закрыто', id, reason);
            delete clients[id];
        });
        ws.on('error', err => {
            console.error(err);
        });
    });
};
```

Логично предположить, что событие `on message` происходит сразу после `on end`

Comment: Да не, я просто заменил две строчки с записью потока - на строчку с "записать файл".

Comment: Хе. И я всё таки попробовал так (дураццкий характер), и да, поток нормально закрывается, и всё нормально заканчивается - работает. С потоком мне больше нравится.